# Segmentation fault while using sqlite in a multithreaded code

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite in a python code to store a list of values and working with multiple threads accessing data and inserting new data into it using the same connection.

As you can see from the code I added below, using a lock I enforce that only one thread insert into the DB at a time (to protect the transactions) while the other threads can fetch data all they want.

While running heavy data load test , I encounter a Segmentation fault problem.

Further inspection into this problem shows that it is happening when one thread is fetching data ("before select") while another thread is committing it's insert statement (between "before commit" and "after commit")

I searched for information on this problem and as far as i could tell it should work:

- "writers and readers can run at the same time. However, since there is only one WAL file, there can only be one writer at a time." (https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) -> the first thing I do is pragma journal_mode=wal
- "Now if only one thread in your application writes and the other threads read you have no serialization issues to worry about." (https://bugs.python.org/issue27113) -> looks like my code works like that
- "The default is SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 which is safe for use in a multithreaded environment." (https://sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe) -> I set it so THREADSAFE=1
- "might not work correctly if the database file is kept on an NFS filesystem." (https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) -> it is not

My code:

```
class Accessor():
  def __init__():
    self.lock = Lock()
    self.connection = sqlite3.connect("db_path", check_same_thread=False)
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')

  def insert(self, id, ...):
    with self.lock:
      #print "before insert"
      cursor = self.connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (id, ...) VALUES(id, ...))")
      #print "after insert"
      #print "before commit"
      self.connection.commit()
      #print "after commit"


  def fetch(self, id):
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    #print "before select"
    r = cursor.execute("SELECT id, ... FROM mytable WHERE id=id").fetchone()
    #print "after select"
    return CONVERT_RESULT_TO_OBJECT(r)
```

The tail of my log file:

```
Thread-1: before select 06815000001kLH6AAM
Thread-2: 01515000004ppihAAA44E5FD2F before insert
Thread-2: 01515000004ppihAAA44E5FD2F after insert
Thread-2: 01515000004ppihAAA44E5FD2F before commit
XXXXXXXXXXXXX: line 35: 32504 Segmentation fault     XXXXXXXX $*
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add `with self.lock:` to the beginning of `def fetch(...)` :

```
def fetch(self, id):
    with self.lock:
        pass # the rest of the code...
```

Comment: This would solve the problem but would make all of the DB access completely serial

Comment: @HarelOz it's either that or manually separating write access and read access to the db.

Comment: I will probably do that but Mainly I would like to know why it is not working even though (based on everything i quoted) it should work just fine